# FFMPEG - chaining - Video, audio, ASS subtitle, then overlay logo?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have this to use a video, replace audio, and add subtitles:

> ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -an -i "E:\video.mp4"  -vn -i
> "E:\audio.mp3"  -vf "subtitles=E\:\\sub.txt" -map 0:v -map 1:a -b:v
> 4M -maxrate 4M  "E:\output.mp4" -y

I could not figure out how to add one more to the chain, such as adding a logo at the bottom right

What I've tried so far, after hours (still not working)

> ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda  -an -i "E:\video.mp4"  -vn -i
> "E:\audio.mp3" -i "E:\logo.png" -vf "subtitles=E\:\\sub.txt" -map
> 0:v -map 1:a -preset ultrafast -filter_complex
> "[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[logo];[0][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto,format=yuv420p" "E:\output.mp4"   -y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All filtering should be performed in the complex filtergraph. First burn subs on main video, then overlay logo on that result.

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -an -i "E:\video.mp4" -vn -i "E:\audio.mp3" -i "E:\logo.png" -filter_complex "[2]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[logo];[v][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto,format=yuv420p,subtitles=E\:\\sub.txt" -b:v 4M -maxrate 4M "E:\output.mp4" -y`

Comment: Got an error: Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description [0]subtitles=E\\:sub.ass[v];[1]format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[logo];[v][logo]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto,format=yuv420p matches a disabled input stream.

Comment: Corrected filter pad.

Comment: while that works, when rendered, the logo is on top of the burned-in subtitles.

Comment: You didn't specify the order you wanted. Changed.